# How do I stop Xubuntu 13.10 from suspending when I close lid?

Tags: xubuntu, laptop, power-management, suspend, xfce

I just upgraded to 13.10 and tried configuring at the Settings Manager, but it doesn't seem to work. So I tried configuring xfce4-power-manager/lid-action-on-ac and it didn't work eiter. Then, at last, tried editing /etc/systemd/logind.conf to:

```
#HandlePowerKey=ignore
#HandleSuspendKey=ignore
#HandleHibernateKey=ignore
#HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

And `#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited` is marked "yes" by default, but I've tried switching it to "no", with no response.

So, the computer is still suspending when the lid is closed... What else should I try? Or is it Xubuntu 13.10 installation that is bugged?

Comment: have you checked the settings under **Screensaver**? Some time it is screensaver which causes such suspend..

Comment: Screensaver is disabled.

Comment: Strange! I wish some one will help you asap!!

Answer (score 3):

Well, simple answer ...

`#` is a prefix for a line comment, so all lines with `#` are comments.
Simply remove the `#` at lines you want to activate and it will work.

I tried it and it works for me.